# Crear query con valor de un Select

Tags: php, entrada, combobox

De antemano, gracias por su ayuda.

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario en el cual, al momento de seleccionar una opción en un combobox, tome el valor seleccionado y pueda armar un query para poder insertar un valor en un input text. Estoy atorado en como poner el valor del combobox en una variable y así poder armar mi query. (la parte de la conexion a la base y como llamar la cosulta la tengo definida, solo me falta el obtener el valor para integrarlo).
ESte es mi codigo

```
<?php
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_nombre="herramienta";
    $db_usuatio="root";
    $db_contra="";
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuatio,$db_contra,$db_nombre);
    $consulta_tec="SELECT * FROM tecnicos ";
    $consulta_sup="SELECT * FROM supervisores ";
    $consulta_pro="SELECT * FROM proyectos ";
    $consulta_suc="SELECT * FROM sucursales ";

    $list_tecnico=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_tec);
    $list_sup=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_sup);
    $list_pro=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_pro);
    $list_suc=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta_suc);





 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>


<body class="oneColElsCtrHdr">



<center><div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1>Despacho de Ingenieros</h1>
<!-- end #header --></div>
<div id="mainContent">
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
  <table width="200" >
    <tr> 
      <td>Fecha</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hora de Inicio</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="inicio" id="inicio">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hora Final</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="fin" id="fin">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiempo real</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="real" id="real">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tecnico</td>
      <td><label>
              <select  name="tecnico" id="tecnico" value="" ><option 
selected="" value="">[Seleccione a un tecnico]</option>
                    <?php
            while ($fila_tec=mysqli_fetch_array($list_tecnico)){

                echo "<option value='". $fila_tec["Id"] ."'>" 
.$fila_tec["Nombre"] ."</opiton>";



            }

        ?>
        </select>
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Supervisor</td>
      <td><label>
        <select name="supervisor" value=""><option selected="" value=""> 
[Selecciones a un supervisor]</option>
                    <?php
            while ($fila_sup=mysqli_fetch_array($list_sup)){

                echo "<option value='". $fila_sup["Id"] ."'>" 
.$fila_sup["Nombre"] ."</opiton>";


            }

        ?>
        </select>
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proyecto</td>
      <td><label>
              <select name="proyecto" id="proyecto" 
onchange="ShowSelected()" value=""><option selected="" value="" >[Seleccione 
un proyecto]</option>
                    <?php
            while ($fila_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($list_pro)){

                echo "<option value='". $fila_pro["Acronimo"] ."'>" 
.$fila_pro["Acronimo"] ."</opiton>";

                  }
                 ?>

        </select>

      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiempo Proyecto</td> 
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="tiempo" id="tiempo" value="<?php echo 
$user;?>" >
      </label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Sucursal</td>
      <td><label>
        <select name="sucursal" value=""><option selected="" value=""> 
  [Selecciones a un sucursal]</option>
                    <?php
            while ($fila_suc=mysqli_fetch_array($list_suc)){

                echo "<option value='". $fila_suc["SIRH"] ."'>" 
.$fila_suc["Nombre"] . "</opiton>";


            }

        ?>
        </select>
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cd Origen</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="cdorigen" id="cdorigen">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KM</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="km" id="km">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Division</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="division" id="division">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zona</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="zona" id="zona">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SIRH</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="sirh" id="sirh">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </form>
  <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
  <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
 <div id="footer">
<p>Pie</p>
 </div>
</div></center>
```

Es mi primer intento en php así que una disculpa por los errores obvios que cometa.

Saludos y gracias de nuevo!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de esta manera..

```html
<?php
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_nombre="herramienta";
    $db_usuatio="root";
    $db_contra="";
 $conexion = new mysqli($db_host,$db_usuatio,$db_contra,$db_nombre);

 $consulta_tec = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM tecnicos");
 while($tec = $consulta_tec->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_tecnicos = $lista_tecnicos.'<option value='. $tec['Id'] .'>'. $tec['Nombre'] .'</opiton>';
 }

 $consulta_sup = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM supervisores");
 while($sup = $consulta_sup->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_supervisores = $lista_supervisores.'<option value='. $sup['Id'] .'>'. $sup['Nombre'] .'</opiton>';
 }

 $consulta_pro = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos");
 while($pro = $consulta_pro->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_proyectos = $lista_proyectos.'<option value='. $pro['Acronimo'] .'>'. $pro['Acronimo'] .'</opiton>';
 }

 $consulta_suc = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM sucursales");
 while($suc = $consulta_suc->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_sucursales = $lista_sucursales.'<option value='. $suc['SIRH'] .'>'. $suc['Nombre'] .'</opiton>';
 }


 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>


<body class="oneColElsCtrHdr">



<center><div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1>Despacho de Ingenieros</h1>
<!-- end #header --></div>
<div id="mainContent">
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
  <table width="200" >
    <tr> 
      <td>Fecha</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hora de Inicio</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="inicio" id="inicio">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hora Final</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="fin" id="fin">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiempo real</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="real" id="real">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tecnico</td>
      <td><label>
              <select  name="tecnico" id="tecnico" value="" ><option 
selected="" value="">[Seleccione a un tecnico]</option>
        <?php echo $lista_tecnicos;?>
        </select>
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Supervisor</td>
      <td><label>
        <select name="supervisor" value=""><option selected="" value=""> 
[Selecciones a un supervisor]</option>
            <?php echo $lista_supervisores;?>
        </select>
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proyecto</td>
      <td><label>
              <select name="proyecto" id="proyecto" 
onchange="ShowSelected()" value=""><option selected="" value="" >[Seleccione 
un proyecto]</option>
            <?php echo $lista_proyectos;?>

        </select>

      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiempo Proyecto</td> 
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="tiempo" id="tiempo" value="<?php echo 
$user;?>" >
      </label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Sucursal</td>
      <td><label>
        <select name="sucursal" value=""><option selected="" value=""> 
  [Selecciones a un sucursal]</option>
         <?php echo $lista_sucursales;?>

    
        </select>
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cd Origen</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="cdorigen" id="cdorigen">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KM</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="km" id="km">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Division</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="division" id="division">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zona</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="zona" id="zona">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SIRH</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="sirh" id="sirh">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </form>
  <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
  <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
 <div id="footer">
<p>Pie</p>
 </div>
</div></center>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu corrección, ahora me es mas fácil traer la info a los combo box.  <br><br> Como podría hacer para que el valor que seleccione en el combo box me lo guarde en un a variable y así poder crear un query para rellenar el input?. gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

capturas la selección con `$_POST['']` Al enviar el formulario... luego juegas con esas variables... algo así:

```html
<?php
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_nombre="herramienta";
    $db_usuatio="root";
    $db_contra="";
 $conexion = new mysqli($db_host,$db_usuatio,$db_contra,$db_nombre);
 
 $tecnico_seleccionado = $_POST['tecnico'];
 $supervisor_seleccionado = $_POST['supervisor'];
 $proyecto_seleccionado = $_POST['proyecto'];
 $sucursal_seleccionado = $_POST['sucursal'];
 
 $consulta_tec = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM tecnicos");
 while($tec = $consulta_tec->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_tecnicos = $lista_tecnicos.'<option value='. $tec['Id'] .'>'. $tec['Nombre'] .'</opiton>';
  if($tec['Id'] == $tecnico_seleccionado){$nombre_tecnico_select = $tec['Nombre'];}
 }

 $consulta_sup = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM supervisores");
 while($sup = $consulta_sup->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_supervisores = $lista_supervisores.'<option value='. $sup['Id'] .'>'. $sup['Nombre'] .'</opiton>';
  if($sup['Id'] == $supervisor_seleccionado){$nombre_supervisor_select = $sup['Nombre'];}
 }

 $consulta_pro = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos");
 while($pro = $consulta_pro->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_proyectos = $lista_proyectos.'<option value='. $pro['Acronimo'] .'>'. $pro['Acronimo'] .'</opiton>';
  if($pro['Acronimo'] == $proyecto_seleccionado){$nombre_proyecto_select = $pro['Nombre'];}
 }

 $consulta_suc = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM sucursales");
 while($suc = $consulta_suc->fetch_assoc()){
  $lista_sucursales = $lista_sucursales.'<option value='. $suc['SIRH'] .'>'. $suc['Nombre'] .'</opiton>';
  if($suc['SIRH'] == $sucursal_seleccionado){$nombre_sucursal_select = $suc['Nombre'];}
 }


 ?>
```